# Preserve spacing in \verb

Tags: tables, verbatim

I'm writing a document in which I want to insert some Python code.
I wanted to display it in a tabular so I used the

```
\verb
```

tag, it is working pretty well, but it just removes the leading spaces for each instruction, which is problematic as I show Python code ...

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % Marges

%%% For french
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\hline
Boucle & Code \\
\hline \\[-0.2cm]
while & 
\verb|while (condition d'arrêt non vérifiée): | \\
& \verb|    instructions | \\
& \verb|else: | \\
& \verb|    instructions exécutées lorsque le while est terminé|\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My leading verbatim spaces are not removed when I compile your document

Comment: Ugh, on Texmaker I just have 1 space instead of the tab I would like

Comment: Nevermind, solved it by replacing \verb by \Verb ...

Comment: If the issue is tab vs. space, there are questions on that around here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389030/why-doesnt-a-trailing-tab-typeset and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41951/tabs-versus-spaces-for-indenting-tex-documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it much more easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % Marges

%%% Pour le français
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <--- IMPORTANT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}% <--- OBSOLETE
\usepackage[french]{babel}% <--- francais is deprecated

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{booktabs}% <--- better rules

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\toprule
Boucle & Code \\
\midrule
while &
\begin{BVerbatim}[fontsize=\normalsize,baseline=t]
while (condition d'arrêt non vérifiée):
    instructions
else:
    instructions exécutées lorsque le while est terminé
\end{BVerbatim}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that `aeguill` is obsolete and the `francais` option is deprecated (use `french`).

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for all your comments !